# How to find sub-string after matched sub-string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to find sub-string present after the matched sub-string, I want to fetch the sub-string present after "load", here below is the whole string

e.g

```
"load 'element 1'; get 'element 2'; get 'element 3'; load 'element 2';"
```

From the above example I need output like "element 1" and "element 2" only.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I tried inlcude? "load", but it returns true or false only

Comment: Well, that's what `include?` is supposed to return ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str = "load 'element 1'; get 'element 2'; get 'element 3'; load 'element 2';"

str.scan(/load '(.*?)'/)
# => [["element 1"], ["element 2"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`/(?<=load ')([^']*)(?=')/` matches only "`element 1`" and "`element 2`".

Comment: You don't need the second pair of parentheses.

Comment: @sawa: There is slight difference; without it, it would match `load 'element7` at the end of the string without the closing quote. But yes, most likely, it is not needed.